# D3 wrong fill color on start of a transition from line to area

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, transition

I am trying to tween from a line to a area. When starting the animation the fill color of the area (polygon) is black. I tried to asign

```
style("fill", "none")
```

as I wanted it to start from a transparent fill color. But it still keeps fading from black to the desired color.

Here is how I did the transition

```
d3.select("#line")
    .transition()
    .duration(dur)
    .delay(del)
    .attr("d", DATA) // old data was a line, new data is an area 
    .style("fill", "red");
```

Any ideas how to assign a transparent fill color?

Thank you in advanced

Rick

Comment: Why do you want the transition from line to area with a fade in effect...?

Comment: It is a line in a chart wich contains some regular data. Later the line transforms to percentage data that is represented by stacked areas.

Comment: Do you need a fade in effect..??

Comment: Yepp, tweening the line to its position. Gotta look fancy ;) 
It all works great. Beside the black background effect. Assing a green background also works. It starts from a green background. Only "fill" "none" doesn't work.

Comment: Why can't you try the transition the opacity from o to 1...?

Comment: I would have to make the line invisible first. This will result in some kind of flickering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it. The desired property is not "opacity", it is "fill-opacity". 
With

```
d3.select("#line").style("fill-opacity", 0)
    .transition()
    .duration(dur)
    .delay(del)
    .attr("d", DATA) // old data was a line, new data is an area 
    .style("fill-opacity", 1)
    .style("fill", "red");
```

it works like a charm.

Btw. Thank you Prasath for keeping on it.